# Linq OR Operator?

Tags: c#, linq

I have Dogs and Cats classes derived from Animal. I want to find the first black colored animal. I'm currently doing it as follows:

```
Animal blackAnimal = dogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Color == "Black");
if (blackAnimal == null)
{
    blackAnimal = cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Color == "Black");
}
```

I want to be able to do it in the same statement - such that find the first black dog, but if there's no black colored dog, find the first black colored cat.

Notice that the `Color` property is not from `Animal`, but rather independent properties on `Dog` and `Cat`.

Comment: shouldn't the `Color` property be in `Animal` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego Torres answer is perfect but I will provide another way to do it which can be applicable where his solution will not work:

```
Animal blackAnimal = (Animal)dogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Color == "Black") ?? cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Color == "Black");
```

Comment: Not allowing me to do this either - Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dog' and 'Cat'.

Comment: This should be `dogs.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Color == "Black") as Animal ?? cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Color == "Black") as Animal;`

Comment: @Gengis yes sorry, it has to be casted otherwise it will not be able to find a best match

Comment: This works well, I'm going to select your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GengisKhan Does this answer your question? It's a copy of what you already have in your question.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto did you see the question?

Answer (score 4):

With [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat):

```
dogs
    .Cast<Animal>()
    .Concat(cats)
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Color == "Black");
```

It will enumerate the second collection after the first.

---

Since you are searching on different properties then you can do

```
var result = dogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Color1 == "Black") as Animal ??
             cats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Color2 == "Black");
```

Comment: This might require `Cast` in case `dogs` and `cats` are collections of the child classes and not the `Animal` class.

Comment: Yes, currently it's not allowing me to do it as Diego suggested.

Comment: @GengisKhan right, I forgot about the different types, now I have updated and tested my answer.

Comment: I forgot another important point, which makes this a little more complicated. Color is not a property of Animal, but both Dog and Cat have it. As a reason, the above solution doesn't work.

Comment: @GengisKhan That doesn't make any sense, can't you just add it to Animal? Or use an interface?

Comment: I know, but not all animals have color property, so it's only added to the ones where it's required. Doesn't make much sense to me either, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `.Cast` it all if the collections are not of the base type.

Given that `Color` is not a property of Animal, you will have to do something like this:

```
var animal = dogs
    // check for dogs
    .Where(d => d.Color == "Black").Cast<Animal>()
    // check for cats
    .Concat(cats.Where(c => c.Color == "Black").Cast<Animal>())
    // get the first
    .FirstOrDefault();
```